# How do I $cond a $push/$pull in a MongoDB update with upsert:true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do a push or pull based on a condition, along with an upsert

```
    myCollection.update(
  {'id': location},
  {
    $set: { count },
    $setOnInsert: {
      id: location,
      users: []
    },
  },
  {
    $cond: {
      if: (increment==1),
      then: {$push: { users: userToken }},
      else: {$pull: { users: userToken }}
    }
  },
  {'upsert':true},
  (err, data) => {
    ...
```

I'm trying to DRY this up (which works):

```
    mongo.connect(dbUrl, (err, db) => {
if (err) throw err
let myCollection = db.collection('myCollection')
if(increment==1){
  myCollection.update(
    {'id': location},
    {
      $set: { count },
      $push: { users: userToken },
      $setOnInsert: {
        id: location
      }
    },
    {'upsert':true},
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(data);
      callback()
      db.close()
    }
  )
}
else{
  myCollection.update(
    ...
    $pull: { users: userToken },
    ...
  )
}
```

})

It's not adding anything to the DB when I have $cond. Where should the $cond be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** is not applicable here but in the aggregation framework. What you need is a pure old native JS conditional statement where you create the update document prior to using it in the update operation, and this of course should be set in a condition block. Consider the following example:

```
let queryObj = { 'id': location },
    usersObj = { 'users': userToken },
    updateObj = { 
        '$set': { count },
        '$setOnInsert': queryObj
    },
    options = { 'upsert': true },
    updateOperator = '$pull';

if (increment == 1) updateOperator = '$push';
updateObj[updateOperator] = usersObj;

myCollection.update(queryObj, updateObj, options,
    (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(data);
        callback();
        db.close();
    }
)
```